# get the properties of jquery ui tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

just one quick question about the `select` event of the [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
   select: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

I know I can get the index of the selected tab inside the callback function by doing:

```
ui.index
```

But my question is, how do I get all the properties that are available to me from the `ui` object? (`ui.index` for example is just one of them). What are the other `ui.SOMETHING` that are available to me for use? (apart from `index`, what else can `SOMETHING` be replaced by?)

Anybody please let me know

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to find out yourself by logging "ui" to console:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
      console.dir( ui);
    }
});
```